# How to modify catch block code using ASM Bytecode framework

Tags: java, java-bytecode-asm

I am trying to change the code content of catch block of existing try/catch block inside a method.

```
public static void hello(Throwable throwable) {
    try{
        System.out.println("in try");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("in catch");
    }
}
```

My intention is to add a method call inside catch block. Something like,

```
public static void hello(Throwable throwable) {
    try{
        System.out.println("in Try");
    }catch(Exception e){
        *passException(e);*
        System.out.println("in catch");
    }
}
```

**Note:** I have already tried to override `visitTryCatchBlock` method of `MethodVisitor`. And experimented with visiting the label in many ways but nothing helped. I can't find this in any of the documentation/guide/examples on the net. I hope I have explained clearly that I am posting this question after trying everything.

Comment: Please at least put comment when you are down voting this question.

Comment: Maybe someone downvote because your question does not show any effort to solve the problem yourself. It looks currently more you want someone else doing your job. Past the code you have done so far and make clear where your problem is.

Comment: This is the place where i come when i don't have other option. Nobody would like to come here and take the effort of putting the detailed question if other options are open. May be I should put the options i explored before coming here.

Comment: It was a long time since I used the asm package but maybe if you paste your failed attempt with the MethodVisitor someone can spot the problem and help you?

Comment: @Fredrik I am also using ASM package. will post the failed attempt approaches.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Tree API in ASM you can get the class's MethodNode and then the MethodNode's instructions (InsnList). Using the InsnList's toArray() method you can iterate through individual instructions. To edit instructions you would do something like this:

```
for (MethodNode method : classNode.methods) {
    method.instructions.set(insn, otherInsn); // Sets the instruction to another one
    method.instructions.remove(insn); //Removes a given instruction
    method.instructions.add(insn); //Appends to end
    method.instructions.insert(insn, otherInsn); // Inserts an instruction after the given insn
    method.instructions.insertBefore(insn, otherInsn); // Inserts an instruction before the given insn
}
```

Personally I find this the easiest way to edit method bodies.

Answer (score 1):

It’s not clear what actual obstacle you are facing as your description of your attempts points into the right direction, `visitTryCatchBlock` and `visitLabel`. Here is a self contained example which does the job:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import org.objectweb.asm.*;

public class EnhanceExceptionHandler {
    static class Victim {
        public static void hello(boolean doThrow) {
            try {
                System.out.println("in try");
                if(doThrow) {
                    throw new Exception("just for demonstration");
                }
            } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("in catch");
            }
        }
        static void passException(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("passException(): "+e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws IOException, ReflectiveOperationException {

        Class<EnhanceExceptionHandler> outer = EnhanceExceptionHandler.class;
        ClassReader classReader=new ClassReader(
            outer.getResourceAsStream("EnhanceExceptionHandler$Victim.class"));
        ClassWriter classWriter=new ClassWriter(classReader,ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES);
        classReader.accept(new ClassVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, classWriter) {
            private String className;

            @Override
            public void visit(int version, int access, String name, String signature,
                String superName, String[] interfaces) {

                className=name;
                super.visit(version, access, name, signature, superName, interfaces);
            }

            @Override
            public MethodVisitor visitMethod(int access, String name, String desc,
                String signature, String[] exceptions) {

                MethodVisitor visitor
                    = super.visitMethod(access, name, desc, signature, exceptions);
                if(name.equals("hello")) {
                    visitor=new MethodVisitor(Opcodes.ASM5, visitor) {
                        Label exceptionHandler;

                        @Override
                        public void visitLabel(Label label) {
                            super.visitLabel(label);
                            if(label==exceptionHandler) {
                                super.visitInsn(Opcodes.DUP);
                                super.visitMethodInsn(Opcodes.INVOKESTATIC, className,
                                    "passException", "(Ljava/lang/Exception;)V", false);
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void visitTryCatchBlock(
                            Label start, Label end, Label handler, String type) {

                            exceptionHandler=handler;
                            super.visitTryCatchBlock(start, end, handler, type);
                        }
                    };
                }
                return visitor;
            }
        }, ClassReader.SKIP_FRAMES|ClassReader.SKIP_DEBUG);

        byte[] code=classWriter.toByteArray();
        Method def=ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredMethod(
            "defineClass", String.class, byte[].class, int.class, int.class);
        def.setAccessible(true);
        Class<?> instrumented=(Class<?>)def.invoke(
            outer.getClassLoader(), outer.getName()+"$Victim", code, 0, code.length);
        Method hello=instrumented.getMethod("hello", boolean.class);
        System.out.println("invoking "+hello+" with false");
        hello.invoke(null, false);
        System.out.println("invoking "+hello+" with true");
        hello.invoke(null, true);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it’s straight-forward, just record the exception handler’s label in the `visitTryCatchBlock` and inject the desired code right after encountering the code position in `visitLabel`. The rest is the bulk code to read and transform the class file and load the result for testing purpose.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try it and let you know the update. How can i master using  ASM to inject code. I mean is this just keep experimenting with these things or there is some proper guide or documentation.